# How to verify a BFS with generic constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matrix-equations

> Consider the following linear programming problem:
>
> $$\begin{align} \text{min }& c^Tx \\ \text{subject to }&  \left[
>  {\begin{array}{cccccccc}    A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} & 0 & 0
>  & 0 & 0 \\    A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  
>  \end{array} } \right] \left[ {\begin{array}{c}    x_1\\    x_2\\   
> x_3\\    x_4\\    x_5\\    x_6\\    x_7\\    x_8   \end{array} }
> \right] =  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}    b_1\\    b_2\\    5\\    5\\   
> 5\\    5\\   \end{array} } \right];\quad x_{1:8}\geq 0 \end{align}$$
>
> Prove that $x* = (x_1,x_2,0,5)$ is a basic feasible solution to this
>   problem.
>
> NOTE: You can assume $A_{11}A_{22}-A_{12}A_{21}\ne0$.

I understand that given the form of this question $x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8$ are likely slack variables and so don't need to appear in a BFS. However, I can't figure out how to solve for $x_1, x_2$ without knowing any of the $A_{ij}$ or $b_1,b_2$ values since I imagine they're important to making sure $x_1,x_2\in[0,5]$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information to answer this question. What if $x_1=-1$, for example?

Comment: My problem exactly. I was wondering if I was missing some obvious trick.